# How to merge table's column, if having same value, and display same on UI as merged?

Tags: php, html

I have below table:

```
=============================================
Probe Name    IP Address         Credentials
=============================================
NetApp       192.168.20.104    abc/abc123
---------------------------------------------       
VMware       192.168.20.219    abc/abc123   
---------------------------------------------       
NetApp       192.168.20.143    admin/admin
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to merge the column having same value and show it as one as shown in below table. So I want to display O/P using HTML/PHP like where column "Probe Name" data "NetApp" is merged in one row.

```
=============================================
Probe Name    IP Address         Credentials
=============================================
             192.168.20.104    abc/abc123
NetApp       ---------------------------------      
             192.168.20.143    admin/admin
---------------------------------------------
VMware       192.168.20.219    abc/abc123   
---------------------------------------------
```

### Code Snippet:

```
        public function runSql(){


        $sql = "select probe_name from probe_info group by probe_name, ip_address, credential, prerequisite";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;

            return $row['probe_name'];
        }


    }


    public function displayData($sql) {

        try {

            //echo "in displaydata fun";

            $probe = crud::runSql();

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();

            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                    //print_r($row['credential']);

                    ?>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- td><?/*php if (isset($row['ID'])) { print_r($row['ID']); } */?></td -->
                        <!-- td><?php //if (isset($row['probe_name'])) { //echo "<strong>"; print ($row['probe_name']) ; echo "</strong>" ;} ?></td -->
                        <td><?php if (isset($row['probe_name'])) { echo $probe_name; } ?></td>
                        <td><?php if (isset($row['ip_address'])) { print_r($row['ip_address']); } ?></td>
                        <td><?php if (isset($row['credential'])) { print_r($row['credential']); } ?></td>
                        <td><?php if (isset($row['prerequisite'])) { print_r($row['prerequisite']); } ?></td>
                        <td><a href="" title="Edit probe info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a href="" title="Delete probe record"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a></td>
                    </tr>  


                    <?php
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "Message -".$ex.getMessage();
            }
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: This question is a bit better for having code added to it, but there is still no explanation of what problem you are having with that code, despite my having asked explicitly, prior to your edit. Would you edit your question with that information, so that the question is clear to current and future readers? This is a good thing to do on Stack Overflow, even if you have solved the immediate problem you had.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'group' the rows in PHP with the function `array_reduce` and the use of an associative array:

[array_reduce manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [associative arrays manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
$groups = array_reduce($queryRows, function($groupArray, $row) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['Probe Name'], $groupArray) {
        $groupArray[$row['Probe Name']] = [];
    }
    $groupArray[$row['Probe Name']][] = $row;
    return $groupedArray;
}, []);
```

The function iterates over the array `$queryRows` and creates the new associative array `$groupArray` dynamically upon doing this. In each iteration it is checked, if the value from `$row['Probe name']` is already one of the keys in `$groupedArray`. If not, it is set as a new key. Afterwards the row is added to that key in the associative array.

This will create the following data-structure:

```
$groups = [
    'NetApp' => [
        [
            'Probe Name' => 'NetApp',
            'IP Address' => '192.168.20.104',
            'Credentials' => 'abc/abc123',
        ],
        [
            'Probe Name' => 'NetApp',
            'IP Address' => '192.168.20.143',
            'Credentials' => 'admin/admin',
        ]
    ],
    'VMware' => [
        [
            'Probe Name' => 'VMware',
            'IP Address' => '192.168.20.219',
            'Credentials' => 'abc/abc123',
        ]
    ]
];
```

For further information read the provided manuals.

Comment: It is good of you to help, but for every person who has not even opened up their code editor, there's another thousand of them who're grateful for people offering free labour. Thus, a number of us on Stack Overflow would gently ask for people to refrain from answering until a basic effort is evidenced in the question. As it is, the question will hopefully close, since it does not meet the posting guidelines.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the advice. I will look forward to apply to that policy.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, you are most welcome to help as much as you like, but it's worth knowing some people will downvote even on helpful answers, if they are of the view the OP is obviously off-topic. I personally don't do that, but ... `:-)`

Comment: Thanks for answer.  Can you please explain it more as I couldn't understand it above?

Comment: @Rahul Added an explanation for the anonymous callback. Any other information can be found in the really good php.net manuals :-)

Comment: @Philipp  Thanks a lot for help and appreciate it.